# How can I get the first string from a Bash list?

Tags: bash

I do have a Bash list (space separated string) and I just want to extract the first string from it.

Example:

```
 VAR="aaa bbb ccc" -> I need "aaa"
 VAR="xxx" -> I need "xxx"
```

Is there another trick than using a *for* with *break*?

Comment: Possible canonical question (3 years prior, 13 answers, and 135 upvotes) : *[How can I retrieve the first word of the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414)*

Answer (score 11):

Use [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)):

```
echo $VAR | cut --delimiter " " --fields 1  # Number after fields is the 
                                            # index of pattern you are retrieving
```

Comment: In some flavors of Linux it can be ....     echo $VAR | cut -d " " -f 1

Answer (score 7):

Try this format:

```
echo "${VAR%% *}"
```

Another way is:

```
read FIRST __ <<< "$VAR"
echo "$FIRST"
```

Comment: Did you mean to use ## ? Shouldn't that be %% instead?

Comment: This (parameter expansion) is the cleanest solution. Except for using an array in the first place, of course.

Answer (score 7):

If you want arrays, use arrays. ;)

```
VAR=(aaa bbb ccc)
echo ${VAR[0]} # -> aaa
echo ${VAR[1]} # -> bbb
```

Comment: He asked for a "space separated string"

Comment: Substituting the first line with `VAR2="aaa bbb ccc"` and `VAR=($VAR2)` would work.

Comment: `echo ${VAR[0]}` can be reduced to `echo ${VAR}` or `echo $VAR`.

Comment: In the general case, it will fail if e.g. "aaa" is instead "*" (an [asterisk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asterisk#Noun)). It expands to the list of all files and all directories in the current directory...

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how standard this is, but this works in Bash 4.1.11

```
NewVAR=($VAR)
echo $NewVAR
```

Comment: It does indeed work. And it is much simpler (and faster, especially compared to invoking external processes like [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)), [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), or [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)).

Comment: But it will fail if the first "word" is "*" (an [asterisk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asterisk#Noun)) - it expands to the list of all files and all directories in the current directory...

Answer (score 2):

At this moment the only solution that worked, on both Linux and OS X was:

```
 IP="1 2 3"
 for IP in $IP:
 do
   break
 done
```

Comment: Just checked if cut was in Mac OS, found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211943/extract-text-from-hostname)

Comment: `cut` exists but it is not the same, quite an old one in fact.

Comment: I am not sure by what you mean by quite an old one, does it still work? I guess if it works, programs like cut, don't need to be updated every month?

Comment: So old that it doesn't have the parameters used by you :p

Comment: echo $VAR | cut -d " " -f 1     (works on OSX)